# Optimal Query for a problem

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `news` table as following:

```
CREATE TABLE `news` (
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `hash` char(40) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`hash`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And, another `votes` table as following:

```
CREATE TABLE `votes` (
  `hash` char(40) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `vote_type` enum('up','down') DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`hash`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Now I want to get something like this when a user logged in-

> this_is_a_title hash_12312312 NULL
>
> this_is_a_title hash_12312313 up
>
> this_is_a_title hash_12312314 NULL
>
> this_is_a_title hash_12312315 down

Can you suggest an optimal single query for this?

I think my question was not clear. Sorry for that.
By NULL field I meant a new which doesn't has any vote casted from this user or anybody.

---

My version is -

```
SELECT news.*, votes.vote_type
FROM news 
LEFT OUTER JOIN votes 
ON votes.`hash` = news.`hash` 
AND votes.`user_id` = #
```

Comment: Did you want to see all news articles and whether the user has voted on them?

Comment: @Novikov, yes by NULL field I meant a new which doesn't has any vote casted from this user or anybody.

Comment: I don't think your schema works, in the table votes you probably want the PK to be `hash, user_id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've compared with other's solution and so far I'm getting the best solution with this Query. I waited for over a month for any better solution.

```
SELECT news.*, votes.vote_type
FROM news 
LEFT OUTER JOIN votes 
ON votes.`hash` = news.`hash` 
AND votes.`user_id` = #
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM news JOIN votes ON news.hash = votes.hash WHERE votes.user_id = #;
```

This will `SELECT` all votes on news articles for a specific user with id `#`. The tables are joined with `hash` which is a primary key. So it's optimal given your current configuration. You could add an index for `user_id` for additional optimization.

**Note:** Since you are looking for *optimal*, I would encourage you not to use `LEFT JOIN`. Assuming `news` articles will grow over time, using a straight `JOIN` would limit the result set to only votes the user has cast. Which, on average, should be significantly smaller. However, you would need to compensate for this in your logic - i.e. the absence of a news record means no vote versus a `NULL` result.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT news.title, news.hash, votes.vote_type 
FROM news 
LEFT JOIN votes USING(hash) 
WHERE votes.user_id = @my_user_id
```

Here's a good breakdown of different types of joins [What is the difference between Left, Right, Outer and Inner Joins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448023/what-is-the-difference-between-left-right-outer-and-inner-joins)

Answer (score 0):

Being that hash is the primary key of both tables, I believe you only need an INNER JOIN for an optimal query.

```
SELECT
    n.title,
    v.hash,
    v.vote_type
FROM
    votes v
    INNER JOIN news n USING(hash)
WHERE 
    v.user_id=123
```